# pveproxy keep restarting cause my server to freeze on proxmox

Tags: linux, proxmox

The problem i have with this server is the hardware and the OS is running but after 2 days on 10/02/2023 it just crash already gain more times i could remember and it just freeze and doesn't run. i would have to manually power off the power the server itself for it to work again. (please note that this is not the first time i've encountered this issue)

I've tried, cooling down server, change fans, update operating system, update software, update bios, reset cmos, resinstall proxmox (8 times),change ram,increase wattage for the server change the operating system itself.nothing works.

this is the syslog from the records. please help methank you.

```
Feb 10 00:00:29 pve systemd[1]: Starting dpkg-db-backup.service - Daily dpkg database backup service...
Feb 10 00:00:29 pve systemd[1]: Starting logrotate.service - Rotate log files...
Feb 10 00:00:29 pve ceph-mon[233258]: 2024-02-10T00:00:29.634+0800 7ffa831fe6c0 -1 received  signal: Hangup from killall -q -1 ceph-mon ceph-mgr ceph-mds ceph-osd ceph-fuse radosgw rbd-mirror cephfs-mirror  (PID: 751317) UID: 0
Feb 10 00:00:29 pve ceph-mon[233258]: 2024-02-10T00:00:29.634+0800 7ffa831fe6c0 -1 mon.pve@0(leader) e1 *** Got Signal Hangup ***
Feb 10 00:00:29 pve ceph-mgr[233435]: 2024-02-10T00:00:29.634+0800 7f76791226c0 -1 received  signal: Hangup from killall -q -1 ceph-mon ceph-mgr ceph-mds ceph-osd ceph-fuse radosgw rbd-mirror cephfs-mirror  (PID: 751317) UID: 0
Feb 10 00:00:29 pve systemd[1]: dpkg-db-backup.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 10 00:00:29 pve systemd[1]: Finished dpkg-db-backup.service - Daily dpkg database backup service.
Feb 10 00:00:29 pve ceph-mgr[233435]: 2024-02-10T00:00:29.806+0800 7f76791226c0 -1 received  signal: Hangup from  (PID: 751332) UID: 0
Feb 10 00:00:29 pve ceph-mon[233258]: 2024-02-10T00:00:29.806+0800 7ffa831fe6c0 -1 received  signal: Hangup from  (PID: 751332) UID: 0
Feb 10 00:00:29 pve ceph-mon[233258]: 2024-02-10T00:00:29.806+0800 7ffa831fe6c0 -1 mon.pve@0(leader) e1 *** Got Signal Hangup ***
Feb 10 00:00:30 pve systemd[1]: Reloading pveproxy.service - PVE API Proxy Server...
Feb 10 00:00:32 pve pveproxy[751369]: send HUP to 3336
Feb 10 00:00:32 pve pveproxy[3336]: received signal HUP
Feb 10 00:00:32 pve pveproxy[3336]: server closing
Feb 10 00:00:32 pve pveproxy[3336]: server shutdown (restart)
Feb 10 00:00:32 pve systemd[1]: Reloaded pveproxy.service - PVE API Proxy Server.
Feb 10 00:00:32 pve systemd[1]: Reloading spiceproxy.service - PVE SPICE Proxy Server...
Feb 10 00:00:32 pve spiceproxy[751376]: send HUP to 3342
Feb 10 00:00:32 pve spiceproxy[3342]: received signal HUP
Feb 10 00:00:32 pve spiceproxy[3342]: server closing
Feb 10 00:00:32 pve spiceproxy[3342]: server shutdown (restart)
Feb 10 00:00:32 pve systemd[1]: Reloaded spiceproxy.service - PVE SPICE Proxy Server.
Feb 10 00:00:32 pve pvefw-logger[498718]: received terminate request (signal)
Feb 10 00:00:32 pve pvefw-logger[498718]: stopping pvefw logger
Feb 10 00:00:32 pve systemd[1]: Stopping pvefw-logger.service - Proxmox VE firewall logger...
Feb 10 00:00:33 pve systemd[1]: pvefw-logger.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 10 00:00:33 pve systemd[1]: Stopped pvefw-logger.service - Proxmox VE firewall logger.
Feb 10 00:00:33 pve systemd[1]: pvefw-logger.service: Consumed 9.913s CPU time.
Feb 10 00:00:33 pve systemd[1]: Starting pvefw-logger.service - Proxmox VE firewall logger...
Feb 10 00:00:33 pve pvefw-logger[751403]: starting pvefw logger
Feb 10 00:00:33 pve systemd[1]: Started pvefw-logger.service - Proxmox VE firewall logger.
Feb 10 00:00:33 pve systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 10 00:00:33 pve systemd[1]: Finished logrotate.service - Rotate log files.
Feb 10 00:00:33 pve spiceproxy[3342]: restarting server
Feb 10 00:00:33 pve spiceproxy[3342]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 00:00:33 pve spiceproxy[3342]: worker 751407 started
Feb 10 00:00:33 pve pveproxy[3336]: restarting server
Feb 10 00:00:33 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 3 worker(s)
Feb 10 00:00:33 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 751408 started
Feb 10 00:00:33 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 751409 started
Feb 10 00:00:33 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 751410 started
Feb 10 00:00:38 pve spiceproxy[498722]: worker exit
Feb 10 00:00:38 pve spiceproxy[3342]: worker 498722 finished
Feb 10 00:00:38 pve pveproxy[748767]: worker exit
Feb 10 00:00:38 pve pveproxy[750542]: worker exit
Feb 10 00:00:38 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 750542 finished
Feb 10 00:00:38 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 748767 finished
Feb 10 00:00:38 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 742673 finished
Feb 10 00:00:39 pve pveproxy[751423]: worker exit
Feb 10 00:07:01 pve pvedaemon[721894]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 00:17:01 pve CRON[753992]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Feb 10 00:17:01 pve CRON[753993]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 10 00:17:01 pve CRON[753992]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 10 00:22:01 pve pvedaemon[722046]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 00:24:01 pve CRON[755113]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Feb 10 00:24:01 pve CRON[755114]: (root) CMD (if [ $(date +%w) -eq 0 ] && [ -x /usr/lib/zfs-linux/scrub ]; then /usr/lib/zfs-linux/scrub; fi)
Feb 10 00:24:01 pve CRON[755113]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 10 00:24:44 pve pveproxy[751409]: worker exit
Feb 10 00:24:44 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 751409 finished
Feb 10 00:24:44 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 00:24:44 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 755245 started
Feb 10 00:28:21 pve pvestatd[3297]: auth key pair too old, rotating..
Feb 10 00:37:01 pve pvedaemon[722481]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 00:40:29 pve systemd[1]: Starting apt-daily.service - Daily apt download activities...
Feb 10 00:40:29 pve systemd[1]: apt-daily.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 10 00:40:29 pve systemd[1]: Finished apt-daily.service - Daily apt download activities.
Feb 10 00:52:01 pve pvedaemon[722046]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 01:07:01 pve pvedaemon[722046]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 01:08:04 pve pveproxy[751408]: worker exit
Feb 10 01:08:04 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 751408 finished
Feb 10 01:08:04 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 01:08:04 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 762282 started
Feb 10 01:11:07 pve pveproxy[751410]: worker exit
Feb 10 01:11:07 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 751410 finished
Feb 10 01:11:07 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 01:11:07 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 762762 started
Feb 10 01:17:01 pve CRON[763662]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Feb 10 01:17:01 pve CRON[763663]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 10 01:17:01 pve CRON[763662]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 10 01:20:49 pve smartd[2856]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel changed from 56 to 57
Feb 10 01:20:49 pve smartd[2856]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 44 to 43
Feb 10 01:22:01 pve pvedaemon[722481]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 01:37:01 pve pvedaemon[722481]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 01:38:53 pve pveproxy[755245]: worker exit
Feb 10 01:38:53 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 755245 finished
Feb 10 01:38:53 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 01:38:53 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 767140 started
Feb 10 01:52:01 pve pvedaemon[721894]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 01:58:22 pve pveproxy[762762]: worker exit
Feb 10 01:58:22 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 762762 finished
Feb 10 01:58:22 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 01:58:22 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 770493 started
Feb 10 02:07:01 pve pvedaemon[721894]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 02:08:52 pve systemd[1]: Starting systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service - Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Feb 10 02:08:52 pve systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 10 02:08:52 pve systemd[1]: Finished systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service - Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Feb 10 02:08:52 pve systemd[1]: run-credentials-systemd\x2dtmpfiles\x2dclean.service.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 10 02:17:01 pve CRON[773591]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Feb 10 02:17:01 pve CRON[773592]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 10 02:17:01 pve CRON[773591]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 10 02:20:49 pve smartd[2856]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel changed from 57 to 56
Feb 10 02:20:49 pve smartd[2856]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 43 to 44
Feb 10 02:22:01 pve pvedaemon[722481]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 02:26:27 pve pveproxy[762282]: worker exit
Feb 10 02:26:27 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 762282 finished
Feb 10 02:26:27 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 02:26:27 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 775100 started
Feb 10 02:37:01 pve pvedaemon[721894]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 02:44:26 pve pveproxy[770493]: worker exit
Feb 10 02:44:26 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 770493 finished
Feb 10 02:44:26 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 02:44:26 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 777995 started
Feb 10 02:47:23 pve pveproxy[767140]: worker exit
Feb 10 02:47:23 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 767140 finished
Feb 10 02:47:23 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 02:47:23 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 778465 started
Feb 10 02:50:49 pve smartd[2856]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel changed from 56 to 57
Feb 10 02:50:49 pve smartd[2856]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 44 to 43
Feb 10 02:52:01 pve pvedaemon[722481]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 03:06:04 pve pveproxy[775100]: worker exit
Feb 10 03:06:04 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 775100 finished
Feb 10 03:06:04 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 03:06:04 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 781483 started
Feb 10 03:07:01 pve pvedaemon[722481]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 03:10:01 pve CRON[782128]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Feb 10 03:10:01 pve CRON[782129]: (root) CMD (test -e /run/systemd/system || SERVICE_MODE=1 /sbin/e2scrub_all -A -r)
Feb 10 03:10:01 pve CRON[782128]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 10 03:17:01 pve CRON[783227]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Feb 10 03:17:01 pve CRON[783228]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 10 03:17:01 pve CRON[783227]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 10 03:22:01 pve pvedaemon[722046]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 03:37:01 pve pvedaemon[722481]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 03:44:08 pve pveproxy[781483]: worker exit
Feb 10 03:44:08 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 781483 finished
Feb 10 03:44:08 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 03:44:08 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 787496 started
Feb 10 03:52:01 pve pvedaemon[722481]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 04:05:03 pve pveproxy[778465]: worker exit
Feb 10 04:05:03 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 778465 finished
Feb 10 04:05:03 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 04:05:03 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 790793 started
Feb 10 04:07:01 pve pvedaemon[721894]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 04:17:01 pve CRON[792683]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Feb 10 04:17:01 pve CRON[792684]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 10 04:17:01 pve CRON[792683]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 10 04:17:29 pve systemd[1]: Starting pve-daily-update.service - Daily PVE download activities...
Feb 10 04:17:34 pve pveupdate[792768]: <root@pam> starting task UPID:pve:000C18DD:0198FBB3:65C6885E:aptupdate::root@pam:
Feb 10 04:17:36 pve pveupdate[792797]: update new package list: /var/lib/pve-manager/pkgupdates
Feb 10 04:17:40 pve pveupdate[792768]: <root@pam> end task UPID:pve:000C18DD:0198FBB3:65C6885E:aptupdate::root@pam: OK
Feb 10 04:17:40 pve systemd[1]: pve-daily-update.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 10 04:17:40 pve systemd[1]: Finished pve-daily-update.service - Daily PVE download activities.
Feb 10 04:17:40 pve systemd[1]: pve-daily-update.service: Consumed 7.337s CPU time.
Feb 10 04:22:01 pve pvedaemon[722481]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 04:25:15 pve pveproxy[787496]: worker exit
Feb 10 04:25:15 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 787496 finished
Feb 10 04:25:15 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 04:25:15 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 794472 started
Feb 10 04:25:31 pve pveproxy[777995]: worker exit
Feb 10 04:25:31 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 777995 finished
Feb 10 04:25:31 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 04:25:31 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 794504 started
Feb 10 04:37:01 pve pvedaemon[722046]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 04:47:52 pve systemd[1]: Starting man-db.service - Daily man-db regeneration...
Feb 10 04:47:53 pve systemd[1]: man-db.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 10 04:47:53 pve systemd[1]: Finished man-db.service - Daily man-db regeneration.
Feb 10 04:52:01 pve pvedaemon[722481]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 05:07:01 pve pvedaemon[722046]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 05:11:00 pve pveproxy[790793]: worker exit
Feb 10 05:11:01 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 790793 finished
Feb 10 05:11:01 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 05:11:01 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 801816 started
Feb 10 05:17:01 pve CRON[802775]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Feb 10 05:17:01 pve CRON[802776]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 10 05:17:01 pve CRON[802775]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 10 05:18:08 pve pveproxy[794504]: worker exit
Feb 10 05:18:08 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 794504 finished
Feb 10 05:18:08 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 05:18:08 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 802966 started
Feb 10 05:22:01 pve pvedaemon[722046]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 05:25:31 pve pveproxy[794472]: worker exit
Feb 10 05:25:31 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 794472 finished
Feb 10 05:25:31 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 05:25:31 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 804131 started
Feb 10 05:37:01 pve pvedaemon[721894]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 05:52:01 pve pvedaemon[721894]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 06:04:15 pve pveproxy[801816]: worker exit
Feb 10 06:04:15 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 801816 finished
Feb 10 06:04:15 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 06:04:15 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 810328 started
Feb 10 06:07:01 pve pvedaemon[722046]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 06:17:01 pve CRON[812332]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Feb 10 06:17:01 pve CRON[812333]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 10 06:17:01 pve CRON[812332]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 10 06:19:54 pve pveproxy[804131]: worker exit
Feb 10 06:19:54 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 804131 finished
Feb 10 06:19:54 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 06:19:54 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 812813 started
Feb 10 06:20:50 pve smartd[2856]: Device: /dev/sdf [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel changed from 58 to 59
Feb 10 06:20:50 pve smartd[2856]: Device: /dev/sdf [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 42 to 41
Feb 10 06:22:01 pve pvedaemon[722046]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 06:25:01 pve CRON[813604]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Feb 10 06:25:01 pve CRON[813605]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || { cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily; })
Feb 10 06:25:01 pve CRON[813604]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 10 06:29:29 pve systemd[1]: Starting apt-daily-upgrade.service - Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
Feb 10 06:29:29 pve systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 10 06:29:29 pve systemd[1]: Finished apt-daily-upgrade.service - Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Feb 10 06:37:01 pve pvedaemon[721894]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 06:52:01 pve pvedaemon[721894]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 06:52:54 pve pveproxy[802966]: worker exit
Feb 10 06:52:54 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 802966 finished
Feb 10 06:52:54 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 06:52:54 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 818142 started
Feb 10 06:56:50 pve pveproxy[812813]: worker exit
Feb 10 06:56:50 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 812813 finished
Feb 10 06:56:50 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 06:56:50 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 818751 started
Feb 10 07:07:01 pve pvedaemon[722046]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 07:07:58 pve pveproxy[810328]: worker exit
Feb 10 07:07:59 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 810328 finished
Feb 10 07:07:59 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 07:07:59 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 820503 started
Feb 10 07:17:01 pve CRON[821931]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Feb 10 07:17:01 pve CRON[821932]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 10 07:17:01 pve CRON[821931]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 10 07:20:50 pve smartd[2856]: Device: /dev/sdf [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel changed from 59 to 58
Feb 10 07:20:50 pve smartd[2856]: Device: /dev/sdf [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 41 to 42
Feb 10 07:22:01 pve pvedaemon[721894]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 07:27:51 pve pveproxy[818142]: worker exit
Feb 10 07:27:52 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 818142 finished
Feb 10 07:27:52 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 07:27:52 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 823637 started
Feb 10 07:37:01 pve pvedaemon[721894]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 07:47:57 pve pveproxy[818751]: worker exit
Feb 10 07:47:57 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 818751 finished
Feb 10 07:47:57 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 07:47:57 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 826808 started
Feb 10 07:50:50 pve smartd[2856]: Device: /dev/sdf [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel changed from 58 to 59
Feb 10 07:50:50 pve smartd[2856]: Device: /dev/sdf [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 42 to 41
Feb 10 07:52:01 pve pvedaemon[722481]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 08:07:01 pve pvedaemon[722481]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 08:16:03 pve pveproxy[823637]: worker exit
Feb 10 08:16:03 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 823637 finished
Feb 10 08:16:03 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 08:16:03 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 831252 started
Feb 10 08:17:01 pve CRON[831411]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Feb 10 08:17:01 pve CRON[831412]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 10 08:17:01 pve CRON[831411]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 10 08:22:01 pve pvedaemon[721894]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 08:30:52 pve systemd[1]: Starting apt-daily.service - Daily apt download activities...
Feb 10 08:30:53 pve systemd[1]: apt-daily.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 10 08:30:53 pve systemd[1]: Finished apt-daily.service - Daily apt download activities.
Feb 10 08:37:01 pve pvedaemon[722046]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 08:38:55 pve pveproxy[820503]: worker exit
Feb 10 08:38:55 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 820503 finished
Feb 10 08:38:55 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 08:38:55 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 834952 started
Feb 10 08:52:01 pve pvedaemon[722481]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 08:58:58 pve pveproxy[831252]: worker exit
Feb 10 08:58:58 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 831252 finished
Feb 10 08:58:58 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 08:58:58 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 838104 started
Feb 10 09:07:01 pve pvedaemon[722481]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 09:17:01 pve CRON[840943]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Feb 10 09:17:01 pve CRON[840944]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 10 09:17:01 pve CRON[840943]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 10 09:17:58 pve pveproxy[826808]: worker exit
Feb 10 09:17:58 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 826808 finished
Feb 10 09:17:58 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 09:17:58 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 841099 started
Feb 10 09:22:01 pve pvedaemon[722481]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 09:37:01 pve pvedaemon[722046]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 09:45:02 pve pveproxy[838104]: worker exit
Feb 10 09:45:02 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 838104 finished
Feb 10 09:45:02 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 09:45:02 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 845408 started
Feb 10 09:52:01 pve pvedaemon[721894]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 10:03:02 pve pveproxy[834952]: worker exit
Feb 10 10:03:02 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 834952 finished
Feb 10 10:03:02 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 10:03:02 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 848250 started
Feb 10 10:07:02 pve pvedaemon[722046]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 10:08:04 pve pveproxy[841099]: worker exit
Feb 10 10:08:04 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 841099 finished
Feb 10 10:08:04 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 10:08:04 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 849068 started
Feb 10 10:17:01 pve CRON[850461]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Feb 10 10:17:01 pve CRON[850462]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 10 10:17:01 pve CRON[850461]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 10 10:20:49 pve smartd[2856]: Device: /dev/sdf [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel changed from 59 to 58
Feb 10 10:20:49 pve smartd[2856]: Device: /dev/sdf [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 41 to 42
Feb 10 10:22:02 pve pvedaemon[722481]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 10:37:02 pve pvedaemon[721894]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 10:41:06 pve pveproxy[845408]: worker exit
Feb 10 10:41:06 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 845408 finished
Feb 10 10:41:06 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 10:41:06 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 854249 started
Feb 10 10:52:02 pve pvedaemon[721894]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 10:57:02 pve pveproxy[848250]: worker exit
Feb 10 10:57:02 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 848250 finished
Feb 10 10:57:02 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 10:57:02 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 856754 started
Feb 10 11:07:02 pve pvedaemon[721894]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 11:17:01 pve CRON[859901]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Feb 10 11:17:01 pve CRON[859902]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 10 11:17:01 pve CRON[859901]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 10 11:22:02 pve pvedaemon[722481]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 11:27:06 pve pveproxy[849068]: worker exit
Feb 10 11:27:06 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 849068 finished
Feb 10 11:27:06 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 11:27:06 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 861479 started
Feb 10 11:37:02 pve pvedaemon[722481]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 11:41:05 pve pveproxy[856754]: worker exit
Feb 10 11:41:05 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 856754 finished
Feb 10 11:41:05 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 11:41:05 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 863730 started
Feb 10 11:44:10 pve pveproxy[854249]: worker exit
Feb 10 11:44:10 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 854249 finished
Feb 10 11:44:10 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 11:44:10 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 864241 started
Feb 10 11:50:50 pve smartd[2856]: Device: /dev/sdf [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate changed from 82 to 83
Feb 10 11:52:02 pve pvedaemon[722481]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 12:07:02 pve pvedaemon[722046]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 12:17:01 pve CRON[869443]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Feb 10 12:17:01 pve CRON[869444]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 10 12:17:01 pve CRON[869443]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 10 12:20:49 pve smartd[2856]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate changed from 82 to 83
Feb 10 12:21:11 pve pveproxy[861479]: worker exit
Feb 10 12:21:11 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 861479 finished
Feb 10 12:21:11 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 12:21:11 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 870118 started
Feb 10 12:22:02 pve pvedaemon[721894]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 12:34:16 pve pveproxy[864241]: worker exit
Feb 10 12:34:16 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 864241 finished
Feb 10 12:34:16 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 12:34:16 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 872185 started
Feb 10 12:37:02 pve pvedaemon[722481]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 12:52:02 pve pvedaemon[722046]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 13:07:02 pve pvedaemon[722046]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 13:14:56 pve pveproxy[870118]: worker exit
Feb 10 13:14:56 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 870118 finished
Feb 10 13:14:56 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 13:14:56 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 878721 started
Feb 10 13:17:01 pve CRON[879042]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Feb 10 13:17:01 pve CRON[879043]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 10 13:17:01 pve CRON[879042]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 10 13:22:02 pve pvedaemon[721894]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 13:26:18 pve pveproxy[872185]: worker exit
Feb 10 13:26:18 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 872185 finished
Feb 10 13:26:18 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 13:26:18 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 880498 started
Feb 10 13:29:21 pve pveproxy[863730]: worker exit
Feb 10 13:29:21 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 863730 finished
Feb 10 13:29:21 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 13:29:21 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 880966 started
Feb 10 13:37:02 pve pvedaemon[721894]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 13:50:49 pve smartd[2856]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 7 Seek_Error_Rate changed from 73 to 74
Feb 10 13:52:02 pve pvedaemon[721894]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Feb 10 14:00:01 pve pveproxy[878721]: worker exit
Feb 10 14:00:01 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 878721 finished
Feb 10 14:00:01 pve pveproxy[3336]: starting 1 worker(s)
Feb 10 14:00:01 pve pveproxy[3336]: worker 885875 started
Feb 10 14:07:02 pve pvedaemon[721894]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
```

Proxmox Version.

```
pve-kernel-6.2: 8.0.5
proxmox-kernel-6.5: 6.5.11-8
proxmox-kernel-6.5.11-8-pve-signed: 6.5.11-8
proxmox-kernel-6.2.16-20-pve: 6.2.16-20
proxmox-kernel-6.2: 6.2.16-20
```

Comment: i am unsure, but i think the proxmox forum would be more specific source to your issue imho.

Comment: For a physical server, please contact the vendor and open a support ticket if the device is still under support

Comment: actually i did but no one did respond.